# What does this mean in practice: "Unique application business limit requirements should be enforced by domain models."

Tags: owasp

Regarding the OWASP A5:2017-Broken Access Control, what does the the quote in the title mean? Emphasis on "Unique application business limit" -part.

Answer (score 3):

I guess it is saying that add diff type of business requirement in diff domain model. like create subdomain for different business requirement

A large application has business requirement like application has forum then, suppose example.com is domain. and app has forum functionality so create subdomain for forum is forum.example.com . now we can add different role and different access control on forum.